# Solving PDE using the characteristic method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, substitution, chain-rule

Consider following PDE:

> $u_{xx} - u_{tt} = 2u_t$

And $u$ is a function of $t$ and $x$. This is an example of hyperbolic equation. Using change of variables $v = t - x$ and $w = t + x$, equation becomes:

> $u_{wv} = \frac{-1}{4}(u_v + u_w)$

I don't know how to proceed further with this. Twice integration doesn't work. So it means that characteristic method doesn't work at all for this problem?

Comment: Did you try to take the Fourier transform in $x$?

Comment: @mjez No, I didn't. I want to learn how to solve pde using the characteristic method.

Comment: Well, characteristic method is suitable to solve transport equations, that is equations of the form: $\langle \nabla u , X \rangle = F(x,u)$. Using the flow of the vector field $X$, it reduces to an ODE.

Comment: @mjez So in this case, method of characteristic doesn't give the answer?

Comment: I do not think it does.

Comment: @mjez Okay, thanks a lot.

Comment: In many cases, this damped wave equation can be solved by using separation of variables and Fourier series (several examples on this site). The method of characteristics works well for the wave equation (no right-hand side), and there are some examples on this site too.